# Flutter web image upload to laravel server

Tags: laravel, flutter

I'm using laravel as my backend to upload images. The API I created works successfully as I tested it many times with postman. But when I run code on flutter web, it returns status code of 200 but the image isn't stored. Does anyone have experience with flutter wen upload image to laravel server?
This is the pick function:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                      type: FileType.custom,
                      allowedExtensions: ['png']
                  );
                  if(!result.isNull && result!.files.isNotEmpty){
                    final imageBytes = result.files.single.bytes;
                    uploadImage(imageBytes!);
                  }
```

This is the upload function:

```
try{
      final url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.142.1:5243/api/upload-image');
      final headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      };
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      request.fields.addAll({
        'name': 'test.png',
      });
      request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('image', List<int>.from(imageBytes)));
      await request.send().then((response) {
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          print('Upload Succeeded');
        }
        else {
          print('Upload Failed');
        }
      });
    }catch(error){
      print('Sending Error: ${error.toString()}');
    }
```